# AnyLogic "triggered by rate" implementation

Tags: anylogic

Anybody has a reference for how AnyLogic implements it's rate per day? Specifically, my agent is at different locations (based on time of day) throughout the day. If there are 10 triggers a day, do they happen randomly for each agent throughout the day, or only at the beginning of a day (when agent is at home), etc.?

[image: triggered by rate]

Thank you, Amy! Your explanation was very helpful.

Comment: While Amy explained  it very well, did you try to understand the AnyLogic help on it? It explains it in full detail: https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fstatecharts%2FRate_Event.html&resultof=%22%69%6e%74%65%72%22%20%22%61%72%72%69%76%61%6c%22%20%22%61%72%72%69%76%22%20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rate follows the Poisson distribution.  If you divide 1/rate, you will get an inter-arrival time that follows the exponential.

As this is random, you may not actually get 10 a day - you may get 9 one day and 11 the next.  If you want to get *exactly* 10 in a day, you need to think about writing your own code to make that happen.  That might be something like generating 10 dynamic events randomly sampled times that all trigger a transition in their action code (that would not be exponential between events).

Comment: I just captured time in dataset based on rate of 10 and, like you said, it captured roughly 10 times throughout the day (not exact distribution). Below is the data. The first column is date and second column is hour. thanks again:<br/><br/>

28 0<br/>
28 2<br/>
28 6<br/>
28 9<br/>
28 9<br/>
28 21<br/>
28 21<br/>
28 21<br/>
28 21<br/>
28 22<br/>
29 0<br/>
29 2<br/>
29 5<br/>
29 7<br/>
29 12<br/>
29 13<br/>
29 14<br/>
29 18<br/>
29 21<br/>